# Sorting values in file based on numerical values

Tags: shell, sorting

I have a file containing a list of versions. I am trying to sort the values based on the version number. It is sorting based on number order.

For example:

**1.txt**

```
module-1.0.0-12.tgz 
module-1.0.0-10.tgz 
module-1.0.0-9.tgz 
module-1.0.0-8.tgz
module-1.0.0-7.tgz
module-1.0.0-6.tgz 
module-1.0.0-5.tgz
module-1.0.0-11.tgz
```

I tried the following:

`sort -n` and other some commands, it's not sorting based on version.

```
module-1.0.0-10.tgz
module-1.0.0-11.tgz
module-1.0.0-12.tgz
module-1.0.0-5.tgz
module-1.0.0-6.tgz
module-1.0.0-7.tgz
module-1.0.0-8.tgz
module-1.0.0-9.tgz
```

How can I sort based on the version?

Expected output:

```
module-1.0.0-5.tgz
module-1.0.0-6.tgz 
module-1.0.0-7.tgz
module-1.0.0-8.tgz
module-1.0.0-9.tgz 
module-1.0.0-10.tgz 
module-1.0.0-11.tgz 
module-1.0.0-12.tgz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -V
```

-V, --version-sort
              natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Answer (score 0):

An easy to use and more universal alternative to `-V` option in sort that is a GNU extension, is to just extract the numbers with a proper regex, sort on the numbers and remove extracted numbers.

```
sed 's/^[^-]*-\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4 &/' 1.txt | 
sort -t' ' -n -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4 |
cut -d' ' -f5
```